# App Store: Problem with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: app-store, device, info.plist, capability

I've uploaded my first App to App Store, but I did NOT put on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities that my App requires location-services and wifi. RESULT: the app does not start looking for the coordinates as it should do. (When I've installed the App through XCode in my iPhone 4 it works perfectly).

So, I've tryed to upload a new version with this UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities correctly set, and I got following error message after trying to Upload the new version:

*"The Bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this Application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions."*

So, as I understood, I am NOT able to set the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to this App anymore, is that right?

My idea was: I delete this App, and after that I go through all the steps to submitt the App to the App Store again. But when I clicked on the "Delete this App" button, I got following error message:

*"Deleting it will permanent remove it from iTunes Connect along with any associated in App Purchases. The Application Name and SKU will not be reusable, even once the application is deleted."*

That's very bad, cause I can't change the name of my App. What Can I do to be able to upload a new version of my App with the new UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Comment: have you find the answer mate as i am facing the same problem..thanxs bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename your app in iTunes Connect by submitting a new update which changes the App name.
2. Create a new App in iTunes Connect and enter the original name of your App. (The original name of the App you renamed in step 1)
3. Delete your old app which you have renamed in step 1

Using that trick you can realize your idea. ;-)
The only loss is that you have to enter all your app's meta data again. And don't forget that you will loose the reviews and ratings your customers left on the App Store. (BTW, a good way to get rid of bad reviews. ;-) )

Comment: I just gained this problem but you can't rename apps in itunes connect. At least I can't. I can rename the pending update but not the actual app.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I forgot to mention that: You have to rename your app by submitting an update. I have already done that, so I'm pretty sure it will work. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: create a whole new app!?!? is that a real solution for something like this? what's really going on here?

Comment: i am facing the same problem but my client will never entertain making a new app with new name..

Answer (score 1):

For me I ran into this issue when I recently added HealthKit to my app. I fixed it by removing this row on info.plist.

[image]