# I want to update my universal app to iPad only app in itunes connect. But while submitting binary i am getting following error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, plist

[image]

But when i added my device target as universal. then binary of app is validated successfully.
Please let me know if you have any solution. Really needfull.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible. If you published your app with iPhone support once, all later version will need to support the iPhone as well.

For an iPad only app, you will need to publish it as a new app name with a different name and identifier. However, as you are probably aware you can lose a lot of users that way.

Also see:

- [Apple Technical Q&A QA1623](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html)
- [App Store: Problem with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752025/app-store-problem-with-uirequireddevicecapabilities)

Comment: But what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706215/submit-an-universal-app-as-ipad-only-app-to-apple.

Comment: @AmitB: The mentioned question is about a case where the app has never been published before. I think you are in a different situation.

Comment: ohh But @codo i need to use existing name of my app. Is this possible to submit my existing app with different name and quickly create new app with name that i want?

Answer (score -4):

you need to change two things:

1) Targeted device family has to be only iPad

2) Deployment target must be compatible with iPad (at least 4.3 nowadays).

After that I'd say do a Clean, then Build and Analyze to make sure everything is ok.